# Using cookie in curl call with PHP

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I need to fetch some data from external site. To do this I need to load a site that creates some cookie and gives a simple math calculation to generate new link. This part is easy:

```
$cr = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
$html = curl_exec($cr);
curl_close($cr);
```

After those calls I have cookies stored in cookie.txt:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

domain   FALSE   /       FALSE   0       PHPSESSID       o89t753egbp9pq9084n38eg2m1
```

Now, the question is: how can I load this cookie to use it in my next call to some other site (in the same domain ofcourse)?

Comment: can't you use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); and curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); in both requests?

Comment: cookiefile was the thing I was missing. Thanks. (please, add this as an answer so I'll be able to accept)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($cr, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
```

in both requests.

Answer (score 0):

A cookie is a header, then you can simply use the command setcookie($name,$value), or if you prefer, using the header php call, using Cookie for header name.
Remember, you don't have to send output to the client before the setcookie command.

You have to read file and split it.